# TypeError raised by bytes.join when passing in a byte object

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I am trying to join two bytes objects:

```
header = struct.pack(STRFMT, MAGIC, VERSION,
            command, self.seq, self.session)

data = dataStr.encode() # dataStr is a String

print(type(header)) # <class 'bytes'>
print(type(header)) # <class 'bytes'>

header.join(data)
```

However at runtime I get the following TypeError when calling header.join:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected bytes, int found
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `header + data` here. `b''.join` method iterates over `bytes` object that yields `int` on Python 3:

```
>>> list(b'abc')
[97, 98, 99]
```

See also, [PEP 467 -- Minor API improvements for binary sequences](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0467/#addition-of-optimised-iterator-methods-that-produce-bytes-objects).

Comment: This was not at all clear in the docs! Thanks for the explanation.